# In Ag Grid filtering in not applied on columns that are group by

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

See, in below image when i'm trying to group by one column and then apply filter on them it showing '(Select All)' and '(blanks)' in the filter dropdown instead of actual values that are grouped like '(12/01/2016)','(11/28/2016)' and so on.

below are my group panel gridOptions in Angular

```
vm.gridOptions = {
        showToolPanel: true,
        enableColResize: true,
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableFilter: true,
        enableRangeSelection: true,
        animateRows: true
    };
```

[image]

Comment: So you are expecting to be able to filter out 12/01/2016?

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing that in your columnDefs for your date column you have `rowGroupIndex: 0, hide: true`. So the grid groups by the date and hides/doesn't create the date column... as you instructed. Then when you are trying to filter the grid doesn't know what to filter by since it is all hidden.

Easy fix is to take off `hide: true` so the grid will then create the date column for you to filter on. [Like this example from their website](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/example1.html)

If you mean to report this as a bug that you would like to be fixed please look at [github for this repo](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-enterprise/issues)